# Why the setState() affect all the same widget?

Tags: flutter

When using the BottomNavigationBar widget, I created a list with same class as body.The class used stateful widget, but when I clicked the button to call setState() the other object has affected.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<PlaceHolderView> _children = [
    new PlaceHolderView(currentPage: 0,),
    new PlaceHolderView(currentPage: 1,),
    new PlaceHolderView(currentPage: 2,),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Full Test'),),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.list), title: Text('Data')),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
        ],
        onTap: _changeSelectedView,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _changeSelectedView(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

this is the placeholder view :

```
class PlaceHolderView extends StatefulWidget {
  PlaceHolderView({Key key, this.currentPage}) : super(key: key);

  final int currentPage;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new _PlaceHolderVieWState();
  }
}

class _PlaceHolderVieWState extends State<PlaceHolderView> {
  String str = 'Click Button';

  void _buttonClicked() {
    setState(() {
      str = 'Button Clicked';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Center(
      child:RaisedButton(onPressed: _buttonClicked, child: Text('${widget.currentPage} page\'s button ${str}'),),
    );
  }
}
```

when I clicked the button in one of the pages, the other pages has all changed the str. so I wonder how this happened and how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
setState() method refreshes whole widget who is stateful,
If you want to change state of specific widget at setState(), use it as stateful, and call it in stateless widget.

Comment: I consider that it should create three objects of 'PlaceHolderView' for the 'List', but when I print the 'initState()' method, it only print once on console. So if it means that there are only one object has been created and used for three place.

Comment: Well, using 'IndexedStack' can confirm this PR.Thanks!